# I'm banned from asking questions

Tags: support

Help me I'm banned from asking questions. I had done all the things as mention in 'How can I get out of a question ban?' but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your account was auto-flagged by the system and the time limit has expired. Sometimes if the system notices a trend of poorly received questions or a trend of removed (deleted) questions/answers it will prevent the user from continuing this trend for a certain period of time. Eventually it will becomes unlocked, you just have to wait it out.

Comment: OK, but how much time it will take to?

Comment: @DHL17 See this [answer by Tom](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4452/7355) and this [article on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)